# About Google Android and Google API?

Tags: android, api

I need to know about the Android and the API.

I need information as to what are the latest applications that are developed on Android and/or using API.

Is there any doc that will explain the use of android or the SDK is self-sufficient?

If you can give ideas regarding an application that can be developed as a FYP.

Comment: can you be a little bit more specific?

Answer (score 2):

Like Fredrik pointed out http://developer.android.com is a good place to start.

And like always, why don't you start with a hello world.

- http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html

Answer (score 1):

The documentaion [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html) should be a good start, overall http://developer.android.com has alot of docs & tutorials

Answer (score 0):

For the question about the latest applications on Android, visit [Cyrket](http://www.cyrket.com/), the website is a web accessible client that lets you browse the Android Market without an Android device.

It's fully searchable, shows you the newest apps and (via the bar of icons at the top) the apps that are currently "featured" in the market place.